# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\Colbun\buscar.php on line 7

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, php7, crud

Me sale este error en mi código, y no puedo encontrar que puede ser :(

buscar.php

```
<?php 
    include ("./php/conexion_be.php");
    $codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
    $registros = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM planificacion_faena WHERE id_pt = '$codigo'");
    while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($registros)) {
        echo $registro['id_pt']."".$registro['tipo_personal']."".$registro['tipo_instalacion']."".$registro['planta']."".$registro['puesto_trabajo']."".$registro['fecha']."".$registro['tipo_trabajo']."".$registro['ubicacion']."".$registro['trabajador_asignado'];
    ?>
```

Comment: Te falta la llave de cierre del ciclo while

Comment: Y a `mysqli_query` falta agregarle el link. `mysqli_query($link, $query)` - https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php

Answer (score 0):

Varias cositas, cuanto hagas un query intenta verificar la conexión con la base de datos

```
$consulta = mysqli_query($conexion ,"consulta");
```

Cierra el While para que no te de error

```
while () {

}
```

Comment: Buen aporte pero considera que el error por el cual fue publicada la pregunta es un typo y eso puede generar su cierre